# Post form data to php script using axios

Tags: php, vue.js, vuejs2, http-post, vuetify.js

I'm trying to send the form data to a php script using axios.
Is the syntax of axios correct?
How can I view the data sent via the post method?

I just started programming in vuetify and php, so I need a little help

```
methods: {
      formSubmit(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                let currentObj = this;
                this.axios.post('http://localhost/index.php/',{
                     name : this.name, user : this.username
                })
                .then(function (response) {
                    currentObj.output = response.data;
                })
                .catch(function (error) {
                    currentObj.output = error;
                });
            },
}
```

in the php file there's :

```
<?php
require_once 'limonade.php';

$data = $_POST;


dispatch('/api/', 'test1');
function test1()
{
    return 'Hello';
}

run();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your php only acts when it's a `GET` Call, limonade's `dispatch()` is for GET only.

In your php you are creating a `GET` endpoint on the `/api/` url that will execute the `test1` function. Meaning when you call /api via get, you will get Hello as answer.

if you want that to be POST (without touching your javascript) the php should be something like:

```
 # '/' because you are calling to http://localhost/index.php/ it could be '/whatever' if you call http://localhost/whatever (assuming you have configured everythign as limonade recomends)
function test2()
dispatch_post('/', 'test2'); 
{
    return 'Hello via post';
}
```

Comment: I get this error :  http://localhost/index.php/ 501 (Not Implemented)